# STOP Android navigation bar

Tags: android

how to stop android navigation bar while running the android application? dont hide completely stop the functions ?

i have using this

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE |
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION |
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION |
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
```

Comment: You want to disable onClicks on Navigation bar ?

Comment: Yes i want disable

Answer (score 0):

**If you need to only hide navigation bar than refer this:**

```
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

[image]

**And if you need to full-screen view than refer this:**

```
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

[image]

**For more information [Visit developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation)**

I hope this will helpfull.

Comment: Thanks!! i have tried but this happened hide with fullscreen but when i drag the notification navigation is coming i want no need to support navigation any possible?